# Will BLE peripherals send a Characteristic's value automatically upon subscribing?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

With CoreBluetooth I can subscribe to a peripheral's `CBCharacteristic` using:

```
[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic]
```

After subscribing should I expect to get a `CBPeripheral` delegate callback for `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` with the characteristic having the latest value set in its `value` property?

Or is it more standard to require the central to first explicitly read that value, then subscribe to the characteristic? By "standard" I'm wondering if this is called out or recommended explicitly in the BLE specs somewhere (took a look and couldn't find anything).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBPeripheralDelegate/peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:) is pretty clear on that:

> This method is invoked when your app calls the
>   readValueForCharacteristic: method, or when the peripheral notifies
>   your app that the value of the characteristic for which notifications
>   and indications are enabled (via a successful call to
>   setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:) has changed.

You won't get the delegate callback `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` immediately after subscribing. The peripheral will only send a notification after the characteristic's value has changed. So you have to call `readValueForCharacteristic:` on `CBPeripheral` to get the current value in this delegate callback.

Note that you usually get characteristic's value in `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:` callback. Then you can subscribe to notifications to get notified when the characteristic *changes* its value.

Comment: Thanks, it does sound like that's the case from the Apple documentation. As noted above I was hoping to find out whether the BLE specs state anything explicitly about this. Interesting point about getting the value from `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:`. However, the Apple documentation doesn't seem to state that it's safe to assume this is the latest value. I'll have to play around with that a bit, thanks for the tip!